# Minimize the maximum length of two-segment routes

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Suppose there are N starting points and N directed segments (having beginning and end) on a plane. N routes are constructed by going from some starting point to the beginning of some segment and then to the segment's end. The length of the route is the distance from the starting point to the segment's beginning plus that segment's length. The problem is to find a (one of possibly multiple) one-to-one matching between the starting points and the segments that minimizes the maximum length of the routes in the matching.

Example:
Point X: (100 100)
Point Y:(200 200)
Point Z:(300 300)
Segment S1: beginning (200 230) end (180 220)
Segment S2: beginning (190 190) end (400 400)
Segment S3: beginning (250 250) end (700 700)
One of possible answers:
X - S2
Y - S3
Z - S1

My best attempt was constructing an NxN matrix of route lengths from point i through segment j, iteratively filtering out the maximum element in that matrix and applying the [Hopcroft–Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithm to check that an N-pair matching for the graph generated by the filtered matrix exists. Worst-case performance of this approach is O(N<sup>2.5</sup>)*O(N<sup>2</sup>)=O(N<sup>4.5</sup>). Is there a faster algorithm for this problem?

Also can the algorithm be improved if the coordinates of all points are integers and the length is defined by the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) (i.e. all lengths are also integers)?

Comment: An example would make your question easier to understand.

Comment: Replacing the euclidean by manhattan distance will definitely work, as long as the only usage of the metric is to compare distances. The constraint on coordinates being integers isn't necessary though. This is a minor optimization though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

> constructing an NxN matrix of route lengths from point i through segment j

the optimization problem you face is called [Bottleneck Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_bottleneck_assignment_problem).

[This stack exchange post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32321/weighted-matching-algorithm-for-minimizing-max-weight) discussed an "easy" algorithm which runs in O(N^2.5*log N).

The basic idea is to make a binary search over the parameter t. In each iteration you discard all pairings (matrix entries) with cost > t. Then you perform a bipartite matching algorithm (e.g., [Hopcroft–Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)). If a complete matching was found you decrease the value of t (by halving it), otherwise you increase t (doubling it). You can stop when the possible values for t will not change the input anymore.

Comment: In essence, I just have to replace iterating over all N^2 combinations by binary search over this set, so the number of iterations will reduce to 2*log N. I wonder how I missed it in the first place!